# How do I make one to many relationship to same table in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table called menus.I want to retrieve menus with its child menus.But only parent menus are being retrieved.Child menus result is an empty array.
my table structure is:    id | parent_id | name.
My Menu model one to many relationship is:

```
public function childMenus() { 
    return $this->hasMany( ‘App\Menu’, ’parent_id’); 
} 

public function parentMenus() {
    return $this->belongsTo(‘App\Menu’, ‘parent_id’); 
}
```

My controller Method:

```
public function index() 
{ 
    $menu = new Menu;
    $parent_menus = $menu->where('parent_id', NULL)->get();
    $sub_menus = $menu->childMenus()->get(); 
    return View('admin',compact('$parent_menus’, ‘sub_menus’); 
}
```

When I dive dump sub_menus dd($sub_menus) it returns an empty array.
please anyone help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fetching **childMenus** relation for the newly created **Menu** object stored in **$menu** variable that doesn't have any related child menus, while you should fetch chidlMenus for parent menus that already exist in your database.

The easiest way to load parent menus with their child menus is to do the following (notice there is no need to create a new Menu object):

```
$parent_menus = Menu::with('childMenus')->where('parent_id', NULL)->get();
```

**$parent_menus** will now store collecton of all parent menus and each of them will have their child menus stored in **childMenus** variable. You could iterate parent and child menus with:

```
foreach ($parent_menus as $parent) {
  foreach ($parent->childMenus as $child) {
    //do whatever you need with the child menu
  }
}
```

If all you want is just a collection of all child menus, regardless of what parent they have, just do:

```
$child_menus = Menu::whereNotNull('parent_id')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Actually, my db has parent menus with its child menus.When I dd($parent_menus); it return result but when I do the same for child menus it gives empty result.

Comment: That's because you load child menus incorrectly. You need to access them through the parent menu object like in the example above or, if you just want all child menus in a single variable, see updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your help.Actually I was not retrieving child menus through parent object.It worked now.Thanks again

Comment: One more thing. Can you please tell me how to post form input data in the form of array.For example, I want to save a couple of sub menus at a time to database.When I use name="[]" .Its not working in laravel.

Comment: I'd need to see some code of what you send and how you handle the data in your controller/model. I suggest you create another question and provide all data there

Comment: Ok I will ask it in a new question.